# imap_fetchbody not supported

Tags: php, imap

its my first time using imap. .
so im trying to retrieve email from gmail as plain text using imap, everything works fine, but i got problem when i try to retrieve direct email,

lets say i have first@gmail.com and second@gmail.com and both receiving same email from noreply@site.com

if i retrieve using imap directly from first@gmail.com, the imap_fetchbody return "Your email client is not supported=" in my native language
but if i forwarded the same email from second@gmail.com to first@gmail.com then retrive it on the first email, it works

here is my simplified code

```
$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';

$username = 'first@gmail.com';

$password = 'mypassword';

$inbox = imap_open($imapPath,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect : ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

if($emails) 
{

   $output = '';

   rsort($emails);

   foreach($emails as $email_number) 
   {
      $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);

      echo $message."<br><hr>";
   }

}

else

{

echo "No unseen mail";

}

imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

i've tried changing imap_fetchbody from 1 to 0 and it works but its not the result i need. . 1.1 and 1.2 return empty content
so is there a way so i can retrieve it directly?
thanks advance , sorry if im not describing it clearly/poor english lol

Comment: In Gmail, click on `Settings` then `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` then `Enable IMAP`, it should fix your issue

Comment: @Gab  thx for reply,  its already enabled(by default), i can retrieve other email, but for email from noreply@site.com it said not supported(as i said above), if i retrieve the same forwarded email from the other one it works, is it because its from "noreply" email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by changing

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
```

to

```
$message = strip_tags(quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2)));
```

kinda dirty lol. . 
not sure why some email not supported to fetch as plaintext,but works if the email was forwarded. . i noticed the "Your email client not supported=" appear when i tried to echo the imap_fetchbody plaintext result

solved by fetch it as html and then strip the html tags,maybe its not the appropriate method but i get the result i want using this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so "less secure apps" are allowed https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Have you tried to evaluate the body structure  http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-fetchstructure.php ... I would go for the second answer there

Comment: its already turned on too, its working fine already but  not working on specific email only(in this case email from noreply@site.com), idk if the sender is the issue because same forwarded email works(sender changed to forwarder email)

Comment: i tried what you said. .but still not sure how to fix it, but thanks anyway, "solved" it using temporary method